# Python:Tkinter -- How do I get cursor to show busy status

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make Tkinter show a busy cursor.  Unfortunately, I must be missing something terribly obvious.  Following is a very simple program that reproduces my problem:

```
 from Tkinter import *
 import time

 def do_something():
     print "starting"
     window.config(cursor="wait")
     time.sleep(5)
     window.config(cursor="")
     print "done"
     return

 root = Tk()
 menubar = Menu(root)
 filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
 filemenu.add_command(label="Do Something", command=do_something)
 filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
 menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
 root.config(menu=menubar)
 root.mainloop()
```

I'm not seeing any change in the cursor

Comment: Awesome !   I was missing the 'root.update()' command.  Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make `do_something` like this:

```
def do_something():
    print "starting"
    root.config(cursor="watch")
    root.update()
    time.sleep(5)
    root.config(cursor="")
    print "done"
```

Basically, I did three things:

1. Replaced `window` with `root` (since `window` isn't defined and `root` is the window's handle).
2. Added `root.update()` just after the line that configures the cursor.
3. Removed the unnecessary `return` (this didn't cause any errors, but why have it?).

Comment: got TclError ' bad cursor spec "wait" '.
For me it worked using 'cursor="clock" ' (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: This displays the cursor after the task has finished. Anyone know how to make it so that it shows before?